# What can I use for voluntary donations? (like Tipjoy)

Tags: web-services, paypal, amazon-web-services, donations

There used to be a site called Tipjoy that would let me put a small "donate" button on a webpage, and users could donate small amounts (like 25c) to me easily.

I think it was a pretty neat idea, since I want to have a way for people to give me money, and I don't like advertisements, and I don't update regularly enough to sell subscriptions like bloggers.  I just have some simple web services and open-source program and I want an easy way for people to drop me some change if they think they're useful.

I've found out that Amazon used to have a similar service, but it's also been shut down.

Is there any similar web service available today?  If not, what's the closest thing to offer -- a Paypal link?

Comment: Paypal with a 'Please donate' link to your paypal a/c..it's deemed trustworthy, do not go for anything else other than paypal as it's widely known and regarded as a respectable service.

Comment: Unfortunately I've used Paypay before and I'm not sure *I* trust them.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another similar service I've seen on some sites (including github) is [Pledgie](http://pledgie.com/)